# Load jquery images dynamically for ASPX

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery

i am using .net and  jquery for image popup.

```
 $("#manual2").click(function() {
   var imageNames = document.getElementById("hdImages").value;
        $.fancybox([
            'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg',
            'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg',
            {
                'href'  : 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4213562882_851e92f326.jpg',
                'title' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
            }
        ], {
            'padding'           : 0,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'image',
            'changeFade'        : 0
        });
    });
```

Here i keep images static only,but i want to get images from page load,Now i want load images dynamically from page load.

For the dynamic purpose i saved image urls to **hdImages**('http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg','http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg')

When i write the above jquery like:

```
 $("#manual2").click(function() {
   var imageNames = document.getElementById("hdImages").value;
        $.fancybox([
           imageNames 
        ], {
            'padding'           : 0,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'image',
            'changeFade'        : 0
        });
    });
```

Here not working now.
Plz tell me how to load images to jquery from page load.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean Dynamically ? Loaded them by a variable in code behind ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the aspx page

```
  $("#manual2").click(function() {
    $.fancybox([
        ' ',
        '<%# ImageUrl %>',
        {
            'href'  : '<%# ImageUrl %>',
            'title' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
        }
    ], {
        'padding'           : 0,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'image',
        'changeFade'        : 0
    });
});
```

In the page_load function

```
ImageUrl = "http://..."
....

Page.DataBind()
```

Comment: Thank you for ur response,but here the problem is the number of images will load dynamically means we dont know exact images count for sample purpose i kept 3 images in my post it may between 5 to 30 images

Comment: Well I don't know the exact logic you need to implement for your website. Maybe instead of a string you will use a List of string, but the principle remains the same - load the dynamic portion on the server and databind it to the JavaScript.

Comment: if i have images like http:\\www.xxx.com\1.jpg,http:\\www.xxx.com\2.jpg,http:\\www.xxx.com\3.jpg,http:\\www.xxx.com\4.jpg then how can i pass these images to jquery

Answer (score 0):

manually fire event on `document.ready ex.. $("#manual2").click();`

Answer (score 0):

You should use your function as below script

i.e :

```
 $(function () { 
                     $("#manual2").click(function() {

                           //your script code here..
                        });
   });
```

Hopes its help..